# Creating Oracle view based on SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I need to create a view in Oracle that displays data from a SQL Server table. I'm not sure if there is a database link in SQL Server, and if so how to create one.

has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create and configure `Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server`.

see here. This link will help you in creating and configuring the same.

[Configuring Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm#CIHGADGB)